# Using NHibernate in a class library for both web and windows applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I just changed my NHibernate application to use the [Unit of Work](http://nhforge.org/wikis/patternsandpractices/nhibernate-and-the-unit-of-work-pattern.aspx) pattern. I then continued through this tutorial to the part where it starts using HttpContext to determine whether or not the code is running in an web application. Using Visual Studio 2010 I get the error "The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context". So I added a reference to System.Web and imported the namespace. The sample code then checks whether or not HttpContext.Current is null to determine whether this is a web or windows application. Is this the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 4):

I would go about it a different way. Create a UnitOfWork class that has a Begin and End methods. Then your applications can use these in whichever way you want. So if you were writing a Web app you may want to Begin the unit of work on BeginRequest and End the unit of work on EndRequest. If you're writing a windows application, you might Begin a unit of work when doing an action and End it, when you're done.

The bottom line is, your data layer and unit of work implementation should be independent of the context in which it is used.

Comment: So instead of a using block for UnitOfWork.start(), just have start and end?

Comment: @Chris, you typically wouldn't want to use using blocks for managing a unit of work, anyway (outside of potentially a windows app). However, your implementation of the unit of work class is up to you. If you want to make it disposable and put in a using block that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the [HttpRuntime.AppDomainId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappid.aspx). This should never be null when a thread is hosted in a web server process. `HttpContext` can be null depending on when you check it in the event lifecycle. Asynchronous methods will also show a null `HttpContext` since they're not running in the original web thread.